# Run Python plugins in Hiero

Tags: python, python-2.7, nuke

I am facing a small problem in executing custom made python code from Hiero. As everybody knows, the first place to look for details is the offical documentation "Nukepedia", the Python Dev Guide and the Hiero User Guide. Well according to the Python Dev Guide, Hiero creates a ".hiero" directory by default which lets people add plugin paths to use them in the software. Well, I can't find that directory and I deduced after several tests that Hiero is using the init.py saved in the ".nuke" directory.

So I thought that maybe I could add the plugin paths there but kept getting the famous Import Error for the _fnpython module (before creating Python/Startup directory).

I added Python/Startup folders in .nuke and added the plugins in Startup, I got the same error, I even tried it by adding the path to the plugins in init.py and got the same error too.

Then I created a ".hiero" folder and did the same thing as before but Hiero never took that folder into consideration, I deduced that by printing some strings in the console, Hiero always took the init.py saved in the ".nuke" folder and kept showing the same error.

Finally, I tried to look into the installation process and try to seperate Nuke and Hiero's folders maybe that would create the ".hiero" directory but everything was automated.

The code that I want to run is given by Nuke and Hiero (in the examples directory), I just can't figure out what to do in order to run it from the program.

What should I do in order to fix this problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Marc, Have you fixed your problem?

Comment: Nope, still can't execute the code from Hiero...

Comment: You disappeared last time when we were discussing this issue ))) Let's continue our discussion.

Comment: How do you upload your Python examples?

Comment: I pressed the wrong button and got out of the conversation :(

Comment: No upload, the code was already there under the examples directory. I just want to load it in Hiero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148045/discussion-between-marc-and-andy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup for The Foundry HIERO is a little different than for NUKE.

HIERO has a `core` module. You'll see it in `__init__.py` file:

```
import FnRedirect
import FnPythonFixes
import core
import ui

try:
  if hasattr(core, "taskRegistry"):
    import importers
    import exporters
except ImportError as e:
  pass
```

I'm running HIERO and NUKE STUDIO on a Mac, so there's a full path to HIERO's `__init__.py` file inside package contents:

/Applications/Nuke10.5v5/Contents/MacOs/pythonextensions/site-packages/hiero/`__init__.py`

You need to import this module using:

```
import hiero.core
```

or using a reference to the `core` package:

```
from core import *
```

To find HIERO's current paths you have to run this line in its Script Editor:

```
print hiero.core.pluginPath()
```

Click this link for further details: [Hiero's Environment Setup](https://www.thefoundry.co.uk/products/hiero/developers/2.0/hieropythondevguide/setup.html)

All these instructions are suitable for macOS 10.9 and above. Here are two blocks of steps: first for Terminal Mode and second for UI Mode.

BLOCK 1: `setup for Terminal Sessions`

You need to manually create `.hiero` directory in your `Home` area.

The recommended default location for running Python on startup is:

**~/.hiero/Python/Startup**

**~/.hiero/Python/StartupUI**

Type in your `bash` Terminal (when you're inside your `Home` user directory) the following line:

```
mkdir .hiero/
```

then:

```
mkdir .hiero/Python/
```

and then:

```
mkdir .hiero/Python/StartupUI/
```

then navigate to `Home` directory with:

```
cd ~
```

and check it with:

```
ls -a
```

Also you can specify any number of user-defined paths using the environment variable `HIERO_PLUGIN_PATH`, just like the standard Unix `PATH` environment variable.

For that you need to set up an `environment variable` in `.bash_profile`. To run in Terminal `PICO` editor just type (remember you need an administrator's password for `sudo` command):

```
sudo pico .bash_profile
```

and paste these three lines in it (change `swift` for `<yourName>` and save this file):

```
echo HIERO environment var is set...
export HIERO_PLUGIN_PATH=/Users/swift/.hiero/Python/StartupUI/
export PATH=$PATH:$HIERO_PLUGIN_PATH
```

Write out a file with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>

Exit pico editor with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>

**Restart Terminal**

In Terminal you could print this environment variable typing:

```
printenv HIERO_PLUGIN_PATH
```

You should put inside that `StartupUI` directory `menu.py`, any set of `xxxx.py` or `xxxx.pyc` files, as well as `__init__.py` file.

Now you can use `/Users/swift/.hiero/Python/StartupUI/` path in `Terminal Mode`.

[image]

BLOCK 2: `setup for UI Sessions`

To assign the current paths that HIERO searches when loading plug-ins, you need to create `__init__.py` file with the following lines:

```
import hiero.core

path='/Users/swift/.hiero/Python/Startup/'
hiero.core.addPluginPath(path)
```

After that make `Python/Startup/` subdirectories under `~/.nuke/` folder.

It's not a mistake: I typed `.nuke`.

**Then place this `__init__.py` file into `/Users/swift/.nuke/Python/Startup/` directory.**

**Restart HIERO (or NUKE STUDIO) if it works.**

After that launch HIERO or NUKE STUDIO and run

```
print hiero.core.pluginPath()
```

command in the HIERO's Script Editor or in NUKE STUDIO's Script Editor and you'll see this result:

[image]

After that you'll find new `__init__.pyc` file in `/Users/swift/.nuke/Python/Startup/` directory.

Each package or module discovered when you launch HIERO is imported and added to the built-in package `hiero.plugins`.

TEST 1: `custom_guides.py`

I do not have a commercial version of HIERO so I tested `custom_guides.py` script ( found [here](https://www.thefoundry.co.uk/products/hiero/developers/2.0/hieropythondevguide/examples/index.html) ) using NUKE STUDIO NC.

I placed `custom_guides.py` in `~/.nuke/Python/Startup` directory and then added two lines to NUKE's `init.py` file located in `~/.nuke` directory.

```
import nuke
nuke.pluginAddPath("./Python/Startup")
```

The only thing I could say: `"it works"` Do the same actions as I did and it'll work for HIERO.

Look at `safe_zone` and `masking_ratio` dropdown menus. They are different: before and after.

Before uploading `custom_guides.py` script:

[image]

After uploading `custom_guides.py` script:

[image]

```
# file custom_guides.py contains these lines:

viewer_masks = [
    hiero.ui.guides.MaskGuide("NTSC", 0.91),
    hiero.ui.guides.MaskGuide("PAL", 1.09),
    hiero.ui.guides.MaskGuide("NTSC_16:9", 1.21),
    hiero.ui.guides.MaskGuide("PAL_16:9", 1.46),
    hiero.ui.guides.MaskGuide("Cinemascope 2:1", 2.0)  
]
```

TEST 2: `web_browser.py`

I placed `web_browser.py` file in `~/.nuke/Python/Startup` directory. This Python script creates dockable panel with web browser written with PySide Qt.

[image]

I do not have a commercial version of HIERO so I tested `web_browser.py` script ( found [here](https://www.thefoundry.co.uk/products/hiero/developers/2.0/hieropythondevguide/examples/index.html) ) using NUKE STUDIO NC.

Comment: Ok, no errors cool, but what should I write in the meny.py file under ".hiero/Python/StartupUI" directory ?

Comment: All the things concerning the interactive sessions. It's the same approach as init.py and menu.py for NUKE. This is an excerpt from Developers Guide for NUKE: "Any file called menu.py that is placed in one of NUKE’s plug-in path directories is automatically read when NUKE starts in an interactive session. It is not read, however, when NUKE is launched for a command-line session or render. Because of this, you should use menu.py exclusively for commands that are only relevant to interactive sessions."

Comment: https://www.thefoundry.co.uk/products/nuke/developers/105/pythondevguide/startup.html#menu-py

Comment: Still can't access the plugins

Comment: interactive mode

Comment: Do you have regular version of HIERO or PLE ? In NUKE NC or NUKE PLE user cannot use any plugins.

Comment: It is a regular version, downloaded from the official website

Comment: TEST 1 worked for me, plus there was a problem with the code given originally by nuke so I had to fix the code... and there is no need for a .hiero directory, everything is linked to the .nuke directory.

Comment: I'm glad we've found a solution))